# Visio 2007 - Org Chart generated through wizard - resizing the text

Tags: visio

I'm using the orgwiz command line tool to auto generate an organisation chart to update every night.

It's all working as expected, apart from the fact that the text for some shapes overflows.

Does anyone know if there is a way to autoresize the text automatically somehow, whether that be from the command line or injecting a scripting call to iterate through the pages and resizing the text automagically?  It all has to be done unattended.

Appreciate any help,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Modify the spahe masters so they resize based on the text.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa200988(v=office.10).aspx#377